# how should I use @GetMapping properly to create a /something/{id}/something/{id2} path?

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I've been stuck to this problem for days.
I'm creating a website where chefs can put their buffets, their dishes etc.

This is the code I'm using to get a chef in particular:

```
//cs is the chefService
@GetMapping("/chef/{id}")
   public String getChef(@PathVariable("id")Long id, Model model) {

       Chef chef = cs.findById(id);
       model.addAttribute("chef",chef);
       return "chef.html";
```

(It basically return a page with his buffets)

Now I dont know how to do the same thing for his buffets, precisely i dont know if i have to repeat the id part both for the chef and the buffet or just the buffet id or it's something i need to do in my thymeleaf code.
Is it correct to do it this way? :

```
   @GetMapping("/chef/{idChef}/buffet/{idBuffet}") 
   public String getBuffetsOf(@PathVariable("idBuffet") Long id, Model model) {
       Buffet buffet = bs.findById(id);
       model.addAttribute("buffet", buffet);
       return "buffet.html";
   }
```

Or maybe i need to add another Long variable for the chef id?  Thanks for the help

EDIT: Here are the two entities:

```
@Entity
public class Chef{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String nome;
    private String cognome;
    private String nazionalita;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "chef_buffet")
    private List<Buffet> buffets;


    public Chef(String nome, String cognome, String nazionalita, List<Buffet> buffets) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cognome = cognome;
        this.nazionalita = nazionalita;
        this.buffets = buffets;
    }

    public Chef() {

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getCognome() {
        return cognome;
    }

    public void setCognome(String cognome) {
        this.cognome = cognome;
    }

    public String getNazionalita() {
        return nazionalita;
    }

    public void setNazionalita(String nazionalita) {
        this.nazionalita = nazionalita;
    }

    public List<Buffet> getBuffets() {
        return buffets;
    }

    public void setBuffets(List<Buffet> buffets) {
        this.buffets = buffets;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Chef other = (Chef) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Chef [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", cognome=" + cognome + ", nazionalita=" + nazionalita
                + ", buffets=" + buffets + "]";
    }
```

```
@Entity
public class Buffet {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private String nome;
    private String descrizione;
    private Chef chef;
    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "buffet_piatti")
    private List<Piatti> piattis;


    public Buffet(String nome, String descrizione, List<Piatti> piattis, Chef chef) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
        this.chef = chef;
        this.piattis = piattis;
    }

    public Buffet() {

    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }


    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }


    public String getDescrizione() {
        return descrizione;
    }


    public void setDescrizione(String descrizione) {
        this.descrizione = descrizione;
    }


    public List<Piatti> getPiattis() {
        return piattis;
    }


    public void setPiattis(List<Piatti> piattis) {
        this.piattis = piattis;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    
    public Chef getChef() {
        return chef;
    }

    public void setChef(Chef chef) {
        this.chef = chef;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Buffet other = (Buffet) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Buffet [id=" + id + ", nome=" + nome + ", descrizione=" + descrizione + ", piattis=" + piattis + "]";
    }
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve? I don't see why you would need both chef id and buffet id in the same mapping. If you want the chef, or the chefs' buffets, you would need the chef id. If you need a single buffet, the buffet id is enough. Am i missing a scenario?

Comment: @Chaosfire i want a chef's single buffet. So i need to specify the chef id and the buffet id, dont I?

Answer (score 0):

Since the chef page displays buffets, it makes me believe that you have one-to-many relationship of chef to buffets. When displaying all buffets in chef page, you can build the url for each single buffet in thymeleaf. Something like:

```
/chef/buffet/${buffet.id}
```

Then your mapping for single buffet will be:

```
@GetMapping("/chef/buffet/{idBuffet}") 
public String getBuffet(@PathVariable("idBuffet") Long id, Model model) {
    Buffet buffet = bs.findById(id);
    model.addAttribute("buffet", buffet);
    return "buffet.html";
}
```

Comment: exactly, but what if there is more than 1 chef? Then, only when you pick a chef, you'll be redirected to the buffets page, so I think i need  @GetMapping("/chef/{idChef}/buffet/{idBuffet}"), dont I?

Comment: @leonardomoreo According to your description, the initial page is get chef by id. It's in this page where you display the chefs' buffets. Since you are getting the chef by id, there can only be **one** chef, no more, the id is unique. Also according the the model, buffet has one chef. Since a buffet can't be shared between chefs, this makes chef id redundant.

Comment: Alright I got it, Thank you. I'll change it this way then, since I also have the buffet's dishes page

Answer (score 0):

If you need both chef id and buffet id in the method, you can map both path variables.

```
@GetMapping("/chef/{idChef}/buffet/{idBuffet}") 
public String getBuffetsOf(@PathVariable("idChef") Long idChef,
       @PathVariable("idBuffet") Long idBuffet, Model model) {
       //method code here
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your buffets endpoint,

```
@GetMapping("/chef/{idChef}/buffet/{idBuffet}") 
   public String getBuffetsOf(@PathVariable("idBuffet") Long id, Model model) {
       Buffet buffet = bs.findById(id);
       model.addAttribute("buffet", buffet);
       return "buffet.html";
}
```

You might have missed the {idBuffet} parameter.

Correct code should be,

```
@GetMapping("/chef/{idChef}/buffet/{idBuffet}") 
   public String getBuffetsOf(@PathVariable("idChef") Long idChef, 
     @PathVariable("idBuffet") Long id, Model model) {
       Buffet buffet = bs.findById(id);
       model.addAttribute("buffet", buffet);
       return "buffet.html";
}
```

This should work.

Also, if you are not using {idChef} in your method why would you even need that? You can just create endpoint without that.

Something like,

```
@GetMapping("/chef/buffet/{id}") 
   public String getBuffetsOf(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
       Buffet buffet = bs.findById(id);
       model.addAttribute("buffet", buffet);
       return "buffet.html";
}
```

OR

```
@GetMapping("/buffet/{id}")
   public String getBuffetsOf(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model model) {
       Buffet buffet = bs.findById(id);
       model.addAttribute("buffet", buffet);
       return "buffet.html";
}
```

This will look a lot cleaner.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I put {idChef} because there are many chefs, so i need to path the buffets for every chef. Dont I need to use it?

Comment: Since you are finding buffet by id "Buffet buffet = bs.findById(id);", I don't think you need that. But if you still wish to maintain the path to be "/chef/{idChef}/buffet/{idBuffet}", then you can follow the first approach.